# How to sort user data by id

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project and here I need to fetch data from a MySQL database.
And I need to fetch only that data which contain `38`.
For example - I have a table which contain `user_from` and `user_to` and `msg`. Okay, now I have to fetch all data if `user_from` contain `38`.
So I am able to fetch it but the problem is that is it fetching only one row from database nut I want all row which contain `user_from` `38`.
So Please help me.

As Fast As you can

Codes----

```html
<?php
include 'navigation.php';
include 'conn.php';
if(!$_SESSION["login"]){ 
   header("location:index.php");
   die;
}
if ($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) {
  $id = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
} else {
  echo "Sorry We are unable to get your id";
}
echo "<center><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' id='myBtn'> Send a message </button></center>";
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
select {
 width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Send a Message</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     
  
    
    <label for="Friends">Select Friends:</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="Select Friends">Select Friends...</option>
      <option value="australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>
 <br> <br>
 <textarea cols="149" rows="12"></textarea>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' id='myBtn' name="sendmsgnow"> Send Now </button>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
<?php
$aquery = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE id='$id'";
$aresult = mysqli_query($conn,$aquery);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aresult)) {
 $user_id[] = $row["id"];
}
if (isset($_POST["sendmsgnow"])) {
 $query = "INSERT INTO chats (user_from,user_to,msg_body,userdate,usertime) VALUES ('$id','1','$message','')";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if ($result) {
 echo "Your Message has been sent";
}
}
$b_query = "SELECT * FROM chats WHERE user_from='$id'";
$b_result = mysqli_query($conn,$b_query);
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($b_result)) {
$messages[] = $data["msg_body"];
$user_from = $data["user_from"];
if($user_from==38){
$d_query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE id='$user_from'";
$d_result = mysqli_query($conn,$d_query);
while ($fdata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($d_result)) {
$frname = $fdata["firstname"];
echo "$frname sent you a message <br> $messages[]";
}
} 
}
?>
```

Comment: It may be selecting 1000's, but this line `$user_id = $row["id"];` will only remember the last one it processes in that while loop as its a scalar variable and can only hold one value. Make it an array `$user_ids[] = $row["id"];``

Comment: So What should I do now?

Comment: As pointed out by @RiggsFolly, the loop will overwrite the `$user_id` variable on each iteration. Better would be to add each `$row['id']` to an array and then process that array - though I don't see that variable being used further in the code

Comment: Please Solve the codes and again post it as an answer

Comment: Oh goody, _another do it for me merchant_ SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
You also have to make some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: You can use nested loop for this

Comment: Refresh your page I told you what to do in my first comment

Comment: I also dont see anywhere where you have created a `$message` variable and filled it with anything, but you use it in your first INSERT query

Comment: @Vivek Shukla where do you need your data? I mean which is equal to 38

Comment: Actually I inserted it through phpmyadmin

Comment: @Zain Farooq  Actually it is id of a row

Comment: You have also stored this data in scalar variables from inside a loop `$messages = $data["msg_body"]; $user_from = $data["user_from"];` but that does not matter so much as you have not actually done anything with this data anyway

Comment: @RiggsFolly Please solve the problem and then post it as a  answer I am requesting you

Comment: You are obviously just learning, If I write it for you you will just copy/paste it and not learn anything and this homework assignment will have dont YOU no good at all.

Comment: @Vivek Shukla Can you tell me that from where are you getting `user_from` and where it to be used further?

Comment: Now where do you get `$id` from?

Comment: From Session When user logged in

Comment: Your first query is selecting the `id` column using the `id` column as a known key. Therefore it has no function other than using up CPU cycles for no apparent reason. You need to go have a cup of tea and then start again, having first thought about what it is you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As I told in comments you can use a nested while loop for this
**Updated**

```
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($c_result)) {
    $messages[] = $data["msg_body"];
    $user_from = $data["user_from"];
    if($user_from==38){
        $d_query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE id='$user_from'";
        $d_result = mysqli_query($conn,$d_query);
        while ($fdata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($d_result)) {
            $frname = $fdata["firstname"];


        }

    } //This is end of if
        echo "$frname sent you a message <br> $messages[]";
}//This END of First while loop
```

I have wrote what I have understood. Hope it helps you

Comment: If you indent the code it is a LOT more readable and therefore debuggable

Comment: And now you have got this guy until you have written all his work for him. We call this _the rabbit hole_ and OP will lead you down it, changing his requirements as you attempt to make your answer work for him, until he has bled you dry, and then probably wont even bother to accept your answer. _Good luck_

Comment: @Vivek Shukla  Please explain your problem more precisely or accept answer

Comment: Actually What I am doing is like this-- When I will insert data in database then I want to select it with id like 5 rows are there in database with same id then i want to all 5 rows at once and show it on screen. Now You understood or Again I need to explain you                                                                                       And The output is this 'unexpected []' while echoing the data;

Comment: `Ids` cant be same in database. Your question requires `user_from` to be equal to `38`. And I have fulfilled that requirement

Comment: You can come up with new question. Your this question's requirement has been fulfilled